# sink json like string to a databae with kafka connect jdbc

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

i am producing simple plaintext json like data to kafka with simple kafka-console-producer command  and i want to sink this data to database table. i have tried many ways to do this. but always i get deserializer error or unknown magic bytes error.
there is no serialization and schema validation on that. but the data is always same type.

we cant change the producer configs to add serializer also.

schema :

```
{
  "type": "record",
  "name": "people",
  "namespace": "com.cena",
  "doc": "This is a sample Avro schema to get you started. Please edit",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "first_name",
      "type": "string",
      "default":null
    },
    {
      "name": "last_name",
      "type": "string",
      "default":null
    },
    {
      "name": "town",
      "type": "string",
      "default":null
    },
    {
      "name": "country_code",
      "type": "string",
      "default":null
    },
    {
      "name": "mobile_number",
      "type": "string",
      "default":null
    }
  ]
}
```

Connector :

```
{
  "name": "JdbcSinkConnecto",
  "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector",
  "table.name.format": "people",
  "topics": "people",
  "tasks.max": "1",
  "transforms": "RenameField",
  "transforms.RenameField.renames": "\"town:city,mobile_number:msisdn\"",
  "transforms.RenameField.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ReplaceField$Value",
  "connection.url": "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres",
  "connection.password": "postgres",
  "connection.user": "postgres",
  "insert.mode": "insert",
  "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
  "key.converter.schema.registry.url": "http://http://localhost:8081"
}
```

data sample :

```
{"first_name": "some_name","last_name": "Family","town": "some_city","country_code": "+01","mobile_number": "some_number"}
```

Is there a way to use kafka connect for this ?

Answer (score 0):

> with simple kafka-console-producer

That doesn't use Avro, so I'm not sure why you added an Avro schema to the question.

You also don't show `value.converter` value, so it's unclear if that is truly JSON or Avro...

You are **required** to add a schema to the data for JDBC sink. If you use plain JSON and `kafka-console-producer`, then you need data that looks like `{"schema": ... , "payload": { your data here } }`, then you need `value.converter.schemas.enabled=true` for class of `JsonConverter`

ref. [Converters and Serializers Deep Dive](https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-connect-deep-dive-converters-serialization-explained/#json-schemas)

If you want to use Avro, then use `kafka-avro-console-producer` ... This still *accepts* JSON inputs, but serializes to Avro (and will fix your magic byte error)

---

Another option would be to [use ksqlDB to first *parse* the JSON into a defined `STREAM` with typed and named fields](https://docs.ksqldb.io/en/latest/reference/serialization/#json-objects), then you can [run the Connector from it in embedded mode](https://docs.ksqldb.io/en/latest/how-to-guides/use-connector-management/)

---

By the way, `StringConverter` does not use schema registry, so remove `schema.registry.url` property for it... And if you want to use a registry, don't put `http://` twice